# Border issue with tooltip react js

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I have created a tooltip, need to set the border color for it but it's giving me an error
below image for reference.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5ETc.png)

tooltip code

```
.mytooltip {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: $color-black;
    min-width: 50px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition-property: opacity, transform;
    transform-origin: center center;
    text-align: center;

    &:after {
        border: 1px solid;
        border-width: 6px;
        content: '';
        height: 0;
        position: absolute;
        width: 0;
    }
}
```

bottom direction code

```
.mytooltip--bottom {
    transform: translate(-50%, 15px) scale(0);

    &:after {
        border-color: black;
        border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
        bottom: 100%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -6px;
    }
}
```

please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Can you add the related HTML code as well?

Comment: I am using with react js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use two pseudo-elements.

```css
.mytooltip {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
    min-width: 50px;
    transform-origin: center center;
    text-align: center;
}
.mytooltip:after,
.mytooltip:before {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-width: 6px;
    content: '';
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
}
.mytooltip--bottom:before {
    border-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: gray;
    bottom: 101%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -7px;
    border-width: 7px;
}
.mytooltip--bottom:after {
    border-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mytooltip mytooltip--bottom">this is it!!</div>
```

Comment: Kindly check - `mytooltip` and `mytooltip--bottom` on the same element